# Send email php with Arabic support

Tags: php, sendmail, arabic

I have feedback form. I want to send the content in HTML mail. When user enter Arabic character it don't show right. something like ØªØ¬Ø±Ø¨Ø©

PHP code:

```
function send_email($fromPerson, $fromEmail, $to, $subject, $message) {
    $headers = "From: $fromPerson<$fromEmail> \n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $eMail \r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3 \n";
    $headers .= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
    $headers .= "Bcc:log@tazbeta.com\n";
    $msg=$message;
    @mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

I tried to send Arabic directly from the php code and it arrived correctly, some thing like `$msg = "مثال";`

The problem is when I submit the content from the feedback code.

```
<form name="feedb" method="post" action="subscribe.php" onsubmit="return validate_forms();">
    <input type="hidden" name="feedback_action" value="feed" />
    <div class="fr" style="width:378px;">
      <p class="white fs24 mb4">Give Us Your Valuable Feedback</p>
      <input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" style=" background:#fff; padding:5px; border:none; width:174px; color:#000; font-size:13px;" value="Full Name" onfocus="if(this.value=='Full Name')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Full Name'" />
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" style=" background:#fff; padding:5px; border:none; width:174px; color:#000; font-size:13px; margin-left:5px;" value="Email ID" onfocus="if(this.value=='Email ID')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Email ID'" />
      <div class="cb pb8"></div>
      <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="3" cols="50" style=" background:#fff; padding:5px; border:none; width:366px; color:#000; font-size:13px;" onfocus="if(this.value=='Feedback')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Feedback'">Feedback</textarea>
      <div class="ar mt6">
      <input type="hidden" name="source" value="feedback" />      
        <input name="submit" type="image" src="images/sbmt.gif" />

      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Please, any ideas ?

Comment: most of the time, it's much more convenient and easier to use one of the existing PHP Libraries to send e-mail - they already have these cases implemented in the correct way (http://swiftmailer.org/, https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)

Comment: use 'escape' keyword while submit

Answer (score 1):

```
  /** 
   * Simple UTF-8 mail sender function. This function also encode subject and  
   * plain-text message to UTF-8. If you need HTML mail sender, change the code  
   * in line 2 from text/plain to text/html, but this function is usable the  
   * most cases without any modification. 
   */ 

  function mail_utf8($to, $subject = '(No subject)', $message = '', $header = '') { 
      $_header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n"; 
      mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $_header . $header); 
  }
```

For more information check this [link](http://www.ar-php.org/faq-php-arabic.html#email)

Comment: Assalamu alikoom brorthor khaled.alshamaa, I sow your site (ar-php.org) it's great work may Allah reward you for that. Can you please do tutorials on youtube how to use it ? and if you need any help let me know  ---- Jazak Allahu Khiran

Comment: Life saver. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add this to the phpmailer

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';       
$mail->Encoding     = "base64";
```

Answer (score 0):

add this head tag in your html page:

```
<html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form name="feedb" method="post" action="subscribe.php">
...
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: I already put this meta tag in the header of the page. I've added now another one inside the HTML form and I still have the same error

Comment: you send an email, this email has nothing to do with the page. So you have to add this html-header to your email-html ($msg)

Comment: I've tried. It's not working. I tried also to echo the POST variable of form submission and showed in the same problem as mail.

Comment: @Kamal add `print_r($_POST);` resonse data to your question

Comment: @vahid chakoshy `Array ( [feedback_action] => feed [firstName] => kamal [email] => xxy@gmail.com [comments] => ØªØ¬Ø±Ø¨Ø© Ø¬Ù�Ù�Ù�Ø© [source] => feedback [submit_x] => 48 [submit_y] => 29 )`

Comment: can you add full source of `subscribe.php` in your question?

Comment: @vahid chakoshy Thank you for your help. you put me on the right road! `subscribe.php ` page has a lot of include files. This it is not my code. I find the error and comment it out. It's working.

This function `$_POST = ms_htmlentities($_POST);` I don't know for what? function code `return is_array($var) ? array_map('ms_htmlentities', $var) : htmlentities(trim($var),ENT_QUOTES);`

Answer (score 0):

Make your database encoded with utf8_general_ci in mysql setting.

Comment: This should be a comment